# How do I put all the content of a page that contains the activity stream from buddypress formated by the Youzify plugin into a Shortcode on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, buddypress

I have a wordpress site, with buddypress and Youzify plugins running.
I need to put the Activity Stream as it is on the page designated for that, and put inside another page.
I've tried to include the plugin template, but it won´t work. Because a lot of functions of the template return UNDEFINED

```
add_shortcode( 'activity_stream', 'activity_stream_func' );

function activity_stream() {
    ob_start();
    include '/wp-content/plugins/youzify/includes/public/templates/activity/index.php';
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return  $output;
}
```

This is not the exact code that I used, it´s just the ideia.

Comment: If you open example.com/wp-content/plugins/youzify/includes/public/templates/activity/index.php in browser- its nornal opens with all content what you need ?

Comment: No, i get HTTP ERROR 500, and nothing on error.log